# How to switch off output logs relating style sheet?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

When I run my application, I have many extra logs in Qt Creator "Application Output" tab:

```
[qss_ld] "loading style sheet file \"titlebardockinactive.qsse\"."
[qss_ld] "style sheet file resolved in the default path: \":/styles/blacktheme/titlebardockinactive.qsse\"."
[qss_ld] "processing style sheet file \":/styles/blacktheme/titlebardockinactive.qsse\"."
[qss_ld] "importing style sheet file \"variable.qsse\"."
```

How can I switch off this output logs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the file [QsseFileLoader.cpp](https://github.com/mrkkrj/xamgu-QSS-loader/blob/main/Source/QsseFileLoader.cpp) by [Marek Krajewski (mrkkrj)](https://github.com/mrkkrj/xamgu-QSS-loader), I commented out several lines calling the function:

```cpp
traceFileInfo()
```

and the problem disappears.